# How do i get twitter-feed of particular URL in my application?

Tags: android, twitter-feed

I am developing an Android application. In this application I want the RSS feed of a particular Twitter page. But when I open that URL I didn't find rss icon, so I am not able to get RSS feed.

Can you give me any suggestion how to find RSS feed for that particular page?

Is there any way so that I mention my URL and it will give me rss file of that URL? Give me some suggestion for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just establish a http connection with this url "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/sachin_rt.rss" , where sachin_rt is the user name of sachin tendulkar. U can replace any user name there

U will get a xml file . parse it n get what ever u want.....

Answer (score 1):

Its a little late but this should help you out.

Pull Twitter with PHP
http://www.jamesriter.com/blog/2010/11/03/add-a-twitter-feed-with-php-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

I have not used twitter much, but i just found this that might help you: http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed

Comment: I have already seen this Link.But it does'nt help me more can u suugest me another link or a way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much you can use RSS with twitter, as they largely expose their data via web services.

What is the information you wanted to get? if you just wanted to get users timelines (e.g. just peoples tweets) then you should have a look at Twitter4J - it is a library that provides a standard Java API around the Twitter web services and makes it very easy to access this kind of information.

There is an example walkthrough of a basic android app that uses Twitter4J to load a users timeline using twitter4j (including source code for entire application) [here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-twitter-reader.html):

I know its not RSS - but hopefully it is still a helpful avenue to explore.